# Unexpected Fortran logical comparison

Tags: fortran

When I run the following code:

```
program foo

  implicit none

  logical :: a(2)

  a = [.true., .true.]
  print *, 'a = ', a
  call evaluate(a)

  a = [.true., .false.]
  print *, 'a = ', a
  call evaluate(a)

  a = [.false., .false.]
  print *, 'a = ', a
  call evaluate(a)

contains

  subroutine evaluate(a)
    
    logical, intent(in) :: a(2)
    
    if (a(1) .eqv. .true. .and. a(2) .eqv. .true.) then
      print *, 'TT'
    elseif (a(1) .eqv. .true. .and. a(2) .eqv. .false.) then
     print *, 'TF'
    elseif (a(1) .eqv. .false. .and. a(2) .eqv. .false.) then
      print *, 'FF'
    endif

  end subroutine evaluate

end program
```

I get the following output:

```
 a =  T T
 TT
 a =  T F
 TF
 a =  F F
 TT
```

Why the last call of the subroutine evaluate gives the wrong output (i.e. match the first if condition not the thrid)?
The code has been compiled with the command `gfortran -Wall -fcheck=all foo.f90`.

Comment: What a brilliant example for teaching! The reason is operator precedence - `.eqv.` has a lower precedence than `.and.`, so `.and.` gets evaluated first. This is just like `+` has a lower precedence than `*` so `*` gets evaluated first. Trying putting brackets around the `.eqv.` expressions. Will write a proper answer in a bit.

Comment: @IanBush where did you find this information in the standard (I searched but couldn't find it).

Comment: Off the top of my head I know this - no idea where in the standard. It's table 3.4 in the latest MR&C

Comment: In a draft ISO/IEC DIS 1539-1:2017 standard I, now, found the table in paragraph 10.1.3 "Precedence of operators" in the table Table 10.1: "Categories of operations and relative precedence"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have discovered that the order of precedence of logical operators in Fortran can be a bit confusing. Let's extend your program slightly and see more weirdness:

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ cat eqv_2.f90
program foo

  implicit none

  logical :: a(2)

  a = [.true., .true.]
  print *, 'a = ', a
  call evaluate(a)

  a = [.true., .false.]
  print *, 'a = ', a
  call evaluate(a)

  a = [.false., .true.]
  print *, 'a = ', a
  call evaluate(a)

  a = [.false., .false.]
  print *, 'a = ', a
  call evaluate(a)

contains

  subroutine evaluate(a)
    
    logical, intent(in) :: a(2)
    
    if (a(1) .eqv. .true. .and. a(2) .eqv. .true.) then
      print *, 'TT'
    elseif (a(1) .eqv. .true. .and. a(2) .eqv. .false.) then
     print *, 'TF'
    elseif (a(1) .eqv. .false. .and. a(2) .eqv. .true.) then
     print *, 'FT'
    elseif (a(1) .eqv. .false. .and. a(2) .eqv. .false.) then
      print *, 'FF'
    endif

  end subroutine evaluate

end program
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all -g -O eqv_2.f90
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 a =  T T
 TT
 a =  T F
 TF
 a =  F T
 TF
 a =  F F
 TT
```

Hmmm, so not only [false,false] is [true,true] but [false,true] is [true, false]! How can this happen outside politics?

Well the problem is the precedence of the `.eqv.` operator is lower than that of the `.and.` operator, and so `.and.` gets evaluated first. In fact the precedence of `.eqv.` and `.neqv.` are the lowest of any non-user defined operators in Fortran, so they will get evaluated last in any logical expression that only uses language defined operators. This is just the same as us evaluating `3 + 4 * 5 + 6` as `3 + (4*5) + 6 = 29` and *not* `(3+4) * (5+6) = 77`, because the precedence of `*` is higher than that of `+`.

So you evaluate `.false. .eqv. .true. .and. .false. .eqv. .true.` as

```
.false. .eqv. (.true. .and. .false.) .eqv. .true. = 
( .false. .eqv. .false. ) .eqv. .true. = 
.true. .eqv. .true. = 
.true.
```

Hence the result you see. It is for this reason that I strongly recommend students to use brackets in long logical expressions - if we do this here we get what you expected:

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ cat eqv.f90
program foo

  implicit none

  logical :: a(2)

  a = [.true., .true.]
  print *, 'a = ', a
  call evaluate(a)

  a = [.true., .false.]
  print *, 'a = ', a
  call evaluate(a)

  a = [.false., .false.]
  print *, 'a = ', a
  call evaluate(a)

contains

  subroutine evaluate(a)
    
    logical, intent(in) :: a(2)
    
    if ( (a(1) .eqv. .true.) .and. (a(2) .eqv. .true.)) then
      print *, 'TT'
    elseif ((a(1) .eqv. .true.) .and. (a(2) .eqv. .false.)) then
     print *, 'TF'
    elseif ( (a(1) .eqv. .false.) .and. (a(2) .eqv. .false.)) then
      print *, 'FF'
    endif

  end subroutine evaluate

end program

ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all -g -O eqv.f90
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 a =  T T
 TT
 a =  T F
 TF
 a =  F F
 FF
```

That said as Martin explains in the other answer a lot of this is redundant. In fact I would argue that expressions like `a .eqv. .true.` are not good style, and in fact I can't remember when I last use `.eqv.` or `.neqv.` in a code.

Comment: Great explanation of what is actually quite confusing for those of us who predominantly work in other languages where the `AND` would be evaluated after the equality (or equivalence) checks!

Comment: Thanks, this explain my mistake!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear on why you are checking that `a(1)` and `a(2)` are `true` or `false`.  Their values are, by definition, *true* or *false* and can therefore be used directly without comparing them to `true` or `false`:

```
if (a(1) .and. a(2)) then
  print *, 'TT'
elseif (a(1) .neqv. a(2)) then
  print *, 'TF'
elseif (a(1) .eqv. a(2)) then
  print *, 'FF'
endif
```

The cases are:

1. Both values are `true` = `a(1).and.a(2)` = `TT`
2. The values are not equal = `a(1).neqv.a(2)` = `TF`
3. The values are equal = `a(1).eqv.a(2)` = `FF`

In the third case, they must be `FF` as actually all the other situations have been covered, so an `else` would be sufficient instead of `elseif`.  However, I've left it as the original code had it for clarity.

Output:

```
a =  T T
TT
a =  T F
TF
a =  F F
FF
```

Comment: It is clear that the check with `.eqv.` is a bit redundant , but when it is present the question is why does one land in the third case in the TT part? The later is also for me not obvious (looks like to have to do with the evaluation order, but I couldn't find. quickly, something in the standard).

Comment: It can only be to do with the evaluation order, because otherwise it would work.  Have you tried surrounding the operations with brackets to explicitly test that?

Comment: Seen the comment from @IanBush and my comment with the question I think you should extend your answer a little bit.

Comment: @albert I think given that IanBush has identified the actual problem with the original code that I will leave the answer to them (as they indicated they will leave one).  My answer, although solving the problem, does not address the actual spirit of your question, which is why the evaluation doens't work as expected!

Comment: I have just reported the if statment part of the code, there other operations inside the conditions not present here for clarity. I agree that, as presented, the program is redundant. Thanks you for the reply.